# SSL-mode without CA-cert?

Tags: mysql, authentication, ssl, certificate

I am on DigitalOcean managed databases and they allow to download a CA cert for connecting securely. I am new to this.

In TablePlus I can set SSL-mode to required and still connect without any cert. Is this connection then encrypted all the same? like when browsing to https sites?

What is the difference between a simple SSL-mode required without a cert, or instead setting the SSL-mode setting to "verify-CA" (which does require the cert file in order to connect)?

[image]